# Prime number coprime with the conductor of a monogenic extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a number field, $p$ a prime number and  $\alpha$ an algebraic integer in $L$ such that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. If we call $O_L$ the ring of integers of $L$, I want to show that $pO_L$ is coprime with the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ if and only if $p$ does not divide the Index $[O_L:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$.

I have the following proof, but there are several points that I don't understand.

The conductor $C$ is an $O_L-$ideal with absolute norm $[O_L : C]$, and it is also an $A[\alpha]-$ideal, hence
contained in $A[\alpha]$, so $[O_L : C] = [O_L :A[\alpha]][A[\alpha]:c]$ is divisible by $n = [O_L :A[\alpha]]$.

If $p|n$ then $p|[O_L : C]$ and $pO_L$ must have a prime of $O_L$ above $p$ that divides $C$(I don't understand why).

Conversely, if $pO_L$ is not prime to $C$ then there is a prime $q$ of $O_L$ above $p$ that divides $C$, and it follows that
$p = [O_L : q]$ divides $[O_L : C]$, hence $p$ divides either $[O_L :A[\alpha] ]$ or $[A[\alpha]:C]$. The latter cannot
hold because it would imply that $q$ is an $A[\alpha]-$ideal (Why?), hence divisible by the conductor $C$ (and therefore equal to $C$), but then $[O_L : C] = [O_L : q]$ and $[O_L : A[α]] = 1$ which is impossible when $A[\alpha]$ has nontrivial conductor $C = q$.

Comment: You should never post a question as a [problem statement question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq). Instead, you should provide your own attempt at solving it.

Comment: Sorry, I have justo updated the question